# VBA code executing when Access form opened in design view

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have inherited an Access database which shows some very strange intermittent behaviour, executing a VBA procedure sometimes when objects are either opened or saved in Design mode.

For example, I can SHIFT+OPEN the database to bypass any startup code. But when I open one form in DESIGN view, with nothing else open, a procedure then runs (with errors as the Startup code has not executed.)

Can anyone shed any light on how this might be happening? For example is it possible to specify an event which fires when a form is opened in design mode?

Many thanks,
Jim

Comment: Simply check the code behind the form at issue. See what trigger event is being used.

Comment: I've done that Parfait. I cannot see what event would trigger the code to run. I have even put breakpoints in the code which runs, but this breakpoint seems to get ignored. Also when I get an error, it will not let me CTRL+BREAK out of it, the code just recycles.

Comment: Things to try: decompile then recompile, Compact & Repair, rebuild the form.

Comment: Please tell us what you see or post the code. We can help.

Comment: Thanks Parfait, I have already tried decompile & compact and repair. I am loathed to rebuild the form, but I might have to consider that...

Answer (score 0):

The ribbon callbacks fire - and this occurs EVEN if you JUST open the form in design mode. So you have to use/set the ribbon property in the "other" tab (remove it), and thus no code will run.

So check the forms ribbon setting - that code fires + runs the callbacks and does so EVEN if you jump direct to design mode.

Comment: Hi Albert, 

Thanks for your suggestion. I did wonder about that, but the form and all of the subforms on there (there are a few in a tabbed pages layout - I know....!) have a blank ribbon property.

I have noticed also that this code sometimes does not fire when the form is opened in design view, but DOES fire when the form is being saved.

Comment: Ok, I managed to narrow this down a bit. It turns out that one of the controls on the form has a RowSource which refers to a query which has a function called in the criteria section for one of the columns. This results in an error as the function uses variables which have not been set.

If I remove this string from the rowsource, all good. But my question is: why is this function firing when the form is opened (or saved) when in design mode?

Comment: Interesting (and great find on your part). Access forms when saved often query the data sources to "resolve" values, and the form generates a collection of control values - this process obviously involves a query of the data source of the form and that for controls (such as combo/list boxes).

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there are any other forms loaded that have active timers running.